# Modem online, No internet

Tags: internet-connection, cable-modem

My modem is online but I do not have internet, neither WiFi nor cable. My internet service provider says that it sees the modem online, and that everything is fine with the settings and signal strength. When I restart the modem, the internet is restored, but it takes 5-6 minutes before being lost again.

Technicians were coming in, testing cables, splitters and signal strength, and everything was fine. They even changed the modem 3 times. I am currently using a Tehnicolor CGA2121.

The TV signal I get through the same fiber optic cable works smoothly. Some days the internet will be ok during the day, and from 6pm onwards it will be unusable again. Some other days, the internet is gone all day and all night (with a short establishment time of 5 min).

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: A more aggressive approach to your ISP would seem in order.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry, i'm not very expert, can you explain a little bit more to me?

Comment: Push them harder. Do they have competition? If so, ask to speak to their 'Retention' department and mention your problem in getting stable connectivity. Your state may have a Public Service Commission to complain to.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do exactly that. Only in Serbia is that a long and slow process, and I am out of connection for 28 days...Thanks

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your line, either between your home and the split box if you live in a building, or between your home and the DSLAM if you live in a house. It would be interesting to know the distance between home and DSLAM, in meters, and the "noise" the line does, in dB. It's probably a matter of setting the ping too low. The ping is a signal your modem sends to the DSLAM you're connected to every few milliseconds, to keep the line alive. If it's set too low (too much time elapsed between pings), the line goes dead because the DSLAM is overworked. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 It's a bit technical, but on an xDSL line (and even for some fibers), you've got to choose between (high) speed and (low) latency, but sometimes to the cost of no error corrections: if the line is "bad", or too long, packets get lost and have to be resent by the DSLAM (downlink) or your modem (uplink); that's error correction. A short ping could prevent that, but you might end up with a "slower" connection on the downlink (less Mbps). Some ISPs allow you to set those things up yourself via your customer interface, others don't. If the noise margin is too high (over 6 dB), you can't do it.

Comment: @Didier Thanks man, I will for sure explore the possibilities You wrote. Thank You

Comment: Agree with @Tetsujin. If you're in the US I suggest filing a complaing with FCC [here](https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=39744) citing equipment problems. This will compel your ISP by law to reach out to you and make things right, whether with replacement equipment, discounts or compensation for lost service, etc. Great alternative to waiting on hold to repeat your problem to bottom-tier tech support. I've netted free replacement modems and discounts this way when my ISP has failed to do right by me.

Comment: @DarthContinent op is in serbia not us

Comment: @didier where are you getting this from? - It does not sound right. Are you  confusing ping and interleaving / error correction and packet resends? These are superficially similar but very different  functionally.

Comment: They are not *superficially similar*, they proceed from the same line of reasoning: the keep-alive functionality (ping at a regular interval, whether there's activity on the line or not) is built in xDSL. That's why I mentioned that *some fiber-optic* lines rely on it too, because it depends if you share your public IP at DSLAM level or not. To save on bandwidth and generally speaking overhead, in the absence of traffic to and fro your location, bandwidth on your line will be reduced to next to nil. Setting a ping at too high an interval ("low ping") will result in that too. As for... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 ... error correction (what you call "interleaving", which is something else, but the effect is the same), it's meant to resend packets *when they are missing* (interleaving will resend random packets based on an algorithm that analyses traffic fluctuations on the line). This causes a lot of back and forth on the line, so ISPs resort to resending packets anyway, if connectivity goes down for some reason, based on the asumption that there *will* be some missing packets. I've deployed enough Colt-based xDSL and fiber lines in my time to know how this works.